# Get url params inside a Redux middleware using React-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-redux

I'd like to extract the URL params inside a Redux middleware in order to dispatch an action and use those values in the payload.

Comment: Did you have any joy with what I suggested?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I'm looking for exactly what I asked. If thats not possible then I'll need to find another way. I'm waiting for a little longer and if it's 100% that we can not extract params from the URL then I'll accept your answer.

Comment: I don't think extracting "the URL params inside a Redux middleware" makes sense. Can you point me to the documentation where you've seen anything like that?

Comment: I can not point it.

Comment: Is there any way to map the route params to state?

Comment: Map, as in using `array.map`?

Comment: Not exactly .. There is a "location" key in the state object which is used by multiple components as data source. In the URL (very similar to google maps) I have a parameter called "location" which is a coordinate. My goal is to map that value (with some modification) to the state's "location" key.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38145321/map-a-route-parameter-to-under-a-redux-stores-key

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to achieve your goal , you can use **[redux-router](https://github.com/acdlite/redux-router)**

This library allows you to keep your router state inside your Redux store. **So getting the current pathname, query, and params is as easy as selecting any other part of your application state.**

after that you can **get your params from middleware**

```
export const someMiddleware = store => next => action=> {
    /// get params
    let params = store.getState().router.params;

    ///then do what you want...........
    next(action)
};
```

[MORE INFO](https://github.com/acdlite/redux-router#differences-with-react-router-redux)

Comment: Thanks, I also ended up looking at redux-router as the closest answer for this. Fortunately, the exact solution for my problem (here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38145321/map-a-route-parameter-to-under-a-redux-stores-key) did not require me to change to this router.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to access `params` inside the middleware. A common pattern is just to access `params` via `props` in the component from where you want to dispatch the action.

Something like this:

```
this.props.dispatch(yourAction(this.props.params));
```

Note that you need to make `dispatch` available to your component by using [react-redux Connect method](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options). For example:

```
export default connect()(YourComponent);
```